# Upload and Download a File with Web API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to upload a File , process it and then download the processed file within the same POST request.

I didn't find a lot of documentation about Web API covering my requirement, so I've come up with a solution based on different post's found on the net.

My final solution looks like that:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        task.Wait();
        var requestStream = task.Result;
        var tempFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/App_Data/{0}", fileName));
        var steam = File.Create(tempFile);
        requestStream.CopyTo(steam);
        steam.Close();
        requestStream.Close();
        var modifiedStream = DoStuffToFile(tempFile);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StreamContent(modifiedStream);
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
        return response;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

As I have no experience in Web API, I would like to know if this piece of code is ok,
or if I will run into problems?

**Edit:**

The code works as expected. I'm just not sure if it can cause any problems or side effects for exmaple because I forgot to do something that might be considered by the Web API. Or is it ok that I post a file and send another one back with the response?

Code is also simplified to keep it compact(no check for duplicate files, no cleanup of old files, etc)

Comment: If you want a rough idea of whether it's ok, then maybe compile it and run it; see what happens?

Comment: @anaximander It does what I want, I'm just not sure if there might be side effects or unexpected behaviours when used by many users over time, etc...

Comment: First and obvious is that you're letting your callers provide a file name, so you'll have issues if two simultaneous callers use the same name, and you better not have anything you don't want overwritten in `App_Data`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I know. I'm more concerned about the Web API stuff (the code is simplified to keep it small)

Comment: @gsharp That's fair enough. Pre-edit it looked very much like the sort of "here's some code, will it work?" question that is generally discouraged.

Comment: Further to @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment, do you actually use the user-provided filename in your app? If so, I'd recommend altering it; I tend to prepend "upload_" and stick a timestamp on the end.

Comment: It's probably best to also set the content-type. E.g. if your downsizing a jpeg: httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType =  new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

Comment: @AardVark71 thanks for the typ. will extend it.